# How to get user's client IP from a third party from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using this script to get User's Client IP:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoiplookup.wikimedia.org/"></script>
```

I can get the IP using JavaScript as `Geo.IP`, but I need to get it in code behind on button click.

Something like:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string IP = string.Empty;

    // IP = ???

    // Validation code

}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Derek that'd be in Javascript, as I said, I can handle that by using **Geo.IP**. But how can I get it in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* can't use server variables, or if you need the geo information as well as the IP, you'll need something like the following:

```
<!-- Get geo information -->
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://geoiplookup.wikimedia.org/">
</script>
<!-- JavaScript object-to-JSON -->
<!-- Don't actually hotlink this; host it yourself -->
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js">
</script>
<!-- Hidden field to hold result -->
<asp:HiddenField id="hdnGeo" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
<!-- Script to populate field -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('<%= hdnGeo.ClientID %>').value =
        JSON.stringify(Geo);
</script>
```

This puts the JSON equivalent of the Geo object in your geoiplookup reference

```
{"city":"London","country":"GB","lat":"51.514198","lon":"-0.093100",
 "IP":"193.129.26.250","netmask":"24"}
```

into an ASP.NET hidden field.

Then, on the server, you can access it like:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string json = hdnGeo.Value;
    var dictionary = new JavaScriptSerializer()
        .Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
    string city = dictionary["city"];
    string lat = dictionary["lat"];
    string lon = dictionary["lon"];
    string IP = dictionary["IP"];
    string netmask = dictionary["netmask"];
}
```

Comment: thank you, but what If I have to put the code in Page Load?  How am I sure that the hidden field gets the value before the code is executed? Can't I set the hidden field's value whenever I want from code behind?

Comment: You can't do it on your first page load. You can only do this on a postback, such as is caused by the button click. Until the postback, nothing has been sent to the client, so you can't get anything back from the client. If you don't want to wait for any user input, you'll have to put in something that automatically posts the page back when it is first loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Why the client-side script? [Request.UserHostAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx) sounds like what you're looking for. :)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string IP = Request.UserHostAddress;

    // Validation code

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason Request.UserHostAddress does not work. I think the router is configured in a way that doesnt get information about client IP.

Comment: It [might](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/10/11/A_Gotcha_Identifying_the_Users_IP_Address.aspx) instead be in `ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` if there's a proxy involved, but yes, if OP really only needs the IP, this is much simpler than involving the client-side.

Comment: I displayed all Server Variables, including 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' but all I get is the router's gateway. I think the guy who configured the network has done a really bad job and all i can do now is using a third party client...

Comment: @enb081 `geoiplookup.wikimedia.org` is getting the correct IP from _somewhere_ - you should be able to do it too.

Comment: @Rawling Exactly, but how? I have searched a lot, neither Server Variables nor Request.UserHostAddress seem to work, I always get 192.168.2.1 which is the IP that the router assigns to the requests coming from web.